# Integration Test with Azure AD login

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, integration-testing

I am working on a web application (.NET Core 3.1) that authenticate the user by asking for Identity Claims. When the user first visit the app he/she is sent to Microsoft for login with a username and password to a Azure Active Directory. When logged in the client gets a JWT-token, that is stored in Session Storage. The JWT-token is then used to authenticate each HTTP-request to the web-apps controllers.

How should I require this JWT-token when doing integration Tests (XUnit)? Should the test ask the Azure Active Directory for this token with a HTTP-post to Azure AD, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 2):

There is a really good example of how to achieve that in XUnit and by the following setup:
1. Setup secrets in Key Vault (user credentials, app credentials)
2. Setup integration test configuration (Key Vault URL, API authentication
 settings, add Key Vault secrets to app config)
3. Set the user to use for Key Vault authentication in Visual Studio / AZ CLI
4. Authenticate requests in testing with client credentials for app-only calls
5. Authenticate requests with Resource Owner Password Credentials for calls as a user

This github repo has code samples for the above described approach:
https://github.com/juunas11/testing-aad-protected-apis

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and sorry that I have not accepted your answer yet. I have to do some more research and learn more about Azure and Key Vault, when I get more time. I'm in a bit hurry so I might just mock the authentication part :)

Comment: Is there another way, where I don't have to publish my site on Azure, and use Key Vault?

Comment: Basically, you dont need key vault here, it is just a way to store app settings, so you can put the values you need to appsettings.json, for instance