# Integration testing with Azure ADB2C

Tags: asp.net-core, web-applications, integration-testing, azure-ad-b2c

We have a Web application that is protected by Azure ADB2C. Users must be logged in to access the application. When the user logs into the application we use the API connectors feature to go and fetch more user details using the email the user logged in with. These extra details are added to the token as custom attributes and are consumed by the web app inside the OnTokenValidated event.

When our code is deployed to either the Test/Staging or Production endpoints our integration tests are run against that endpoint. I can't spoof the authentication as the tests are talking to live endpoints. I need to authenticate the tests as if they are a real user.

I have looked around and have tried the ROPC flow that is suggested on similar posts. The trouble is with this solution is that it does not call the API connectors to get the extra user details that the 'normal' login flow would.

ROPC Solution:
[Integration Test with Azure AD login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62281717/integration-test-with-azure-ad-login?rq=1)

How can I make my integration tests authenticate with Azure ADB2C the same way a real user would so that the API connectors are called?

Any help/advice is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you Nasheen Kalam for the blog.

Based on the GIT reference for Integration Test for the Sign up and Sign in Pages

https://git.uwaterloo.ca/jmshahen/ece651-project/-/merge_requests/22

Below are the process:

Run authentication test with pre-defined user

Test Step:
1.Go to application URL: 127.0.0.1:3000
2. Redirect to Sign In page
3. Use registered email and password
4. Sign In
5. Verify Result

Expected Result:

Pass: when email, password is matched

Fail: Error message thrown in case of wrong combination

Run sign up process for new user

Test Steps:

- Manually Remove user if already exists in DB

1.Go to application URL: 127.0.0.1:3000/signup
2. Use full name, email address and password
4. Sign Up
5. Verify Result

Test Data

User name: Test User01
User email: testuser@gmail.com

User Password:
usertest01

Verification text:
Test User01

Expected Result:

Pass: when new user is created

Fail: Error message thrown in case of user already exists

Comment: Thank you for your answer, unfortunately I can't find the elements on the sign in page and populate them with the test data. I have tried this with the angleSharp library and for some reason it doesn't load the form with the document. I suspect this is due to limitation with executing javascript.